Convert overlapped png images to a single one with returning Base64 on javascript, multi browser suport?
There are some png images: 1 of them is not transparent, other - are transparent.
All of it are at Base64 string.
It is necessary to overlap each other, convert overlapped images to monolithic image and return Base64 strig of the resulted single image.
It is necessary to do by iavascript with supporting of main browsers: IE, Edge, Opera, Chrome, Firefox, Safary.
It is NOT necessary to display it all !!
Only conversion and returning is necessary !!
Then it has to be shown at console or to be used in in other javascript functions.
To reach it I use canvas element - create it programmatically and use drawImage:
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Тест 93 !</title>
    </head>
    <body onload="init()">
        <h1>Test 95 !</h1>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            function init() {
                const layer1Data = "data:image/png;base64,...";

                const layer2Data = "data:image/png;base64,...";
                const layer3Data = "data:image/png;base64,...";

                var single = layers2single(710, 750, layer1Data, layer2Data, layer3Data);

                console.log(single);
            }

            function layers2single(w, h, L11, L12, L13) {
                var layers, ctx;
                var img1, img2, img3, img4, img5, img6;
                var dataURL;

                layers = document.createElement("canvas");
                layers.class = "canvas";
                layers.width = w;
                layers.height = h;

                ctx = layers.getContext("2d");

                img1 = new Image();
                img1.onload = function() {
                    ctx.drawImage(img1, 0, 0);
                };
                img1.src = L11;

                img2 = new Image();
                img2.onload = function() {
                    ctx.drawImage(img2, 0, 0);
                };
                img2.src = L12;

                img3 = new Image();
                img3.onload = function() {
                    ctx.drawImage(img3, 0, 0);
                };
                img3.src = L13;


                dataURL = layers.toDataURL();

                return dataURL;
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>

But either empty dataURL is returned or in Chrome, Edge, Opera, not empty dataURL is returned after reload page but even after reload, it can be empty from time to time.
How is to make it stable working in IE, Edge, Opera, Chrome, Firefox ?

You are converting your canvas content to a data URI too early - not all the images have loaded & been drawn onto the canvas at this point. You need to do this only after the load event for all images has fired.

Make your life a bit easier, by saying goodbye to the bad habit of using "numbered" variable names. Use an array instead, to hold your image data URIs. Then you can loop over that, and execute the same code for each. Keep a counter that you increase by 1 each time a load event fires, and then when that counter as reached the overall number of images (checking this still within the load handler callback), you convert your canvas.

I supposed so but I don' t understand how to do so after loading all images.
Can you provide an exaple ?

Keep in mind even microsoft doesn't wnat you to use ie 11 - security support was discontinued in 2022 active development ~2015. So it's definitely no main browser.

As CBroe indicated, you're having a timing issue. Your main function responsible for combining the images - layers2single - is requesting loading and subsequently drawing three images. Afterwards your calling layers.toDataURL().
e.g.
                img1 = new Image();
                img1.onload = function() {
                    ctx.drawImage(img1, 0, 0);
                };
                img1.src = L11;

                img2 = new Image();
                img2.onload = function() {
                    ctx.drawImage(img2, 0, 0);
                };
                img2.src = L12;

                img3 = new Image();
                img3.onload = function() {
                    ctx.drawImage(img3, 0, 0);
                };
                img3.src = L13;


                dataURL = layers.toDataURL();

Unfortunately though things are not happening in that straight order. So sometimes it might occur that the onload event happens after calling toDataUrl.
You can help yourself by making the outer function async and await loading of the images.
function loadImage(src) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let img = new Image();
        img.onload = () => resolve(img);
        img.onerror = reject;
        img.src = src;
    });
}

async function layers2single(w, h, L11, L12, L13) {
    var layers, ctx;
    var img1, img2, img3, img4, img5, img6;
    var dataURL;

    layers = document.createElement("canvas");
    layers.class = "canvas";
    layers.width = w;
    layers.height = h;

    ctx = layers.getContext("2d");

    img1 = await loadImage(L11);
    ctx.drawImage(img1, 0, 0);

    img2 = await loadImage(L12);
    ctx.drawImage(img2, 0, 0);

    img3 = await loadImage(L13);
    ctx.drawImage(img3, 0, 0);


    dataURL = layers.toDataURL();

    return dataURL;
}


Thanks.
It seems it do not work at IE11.
